# Where is the best place to use ini_set in a Laravel application

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-6

What is the best place to run `ini_set` function (to set the whole application value in runtime) in the Laravel application?

**edited:**

The goal is to set `bcmath.scale` value, but eliminate the need for all project developers to touch php.ini in theirs local environments.

Comment: What are you trying to set using ini_set and why? Cant say where is the best place, without knowing what should be set. And there aren't a lot of good use cases for that, so knowing why would help provide a good answer.

Comment: @KurtFriars, the question is edited. Really don't understand why it was downvoted

Comment: Your initial question without the edit was ambiguous. You need to provide exact detail to get good answers. Your question should be, "Where is the best place to set bcmath.scale in a laravel application". Then provide details of where you have tried to set it, and why it is not working.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. But, if somebody will search the similar question answer, not related in bcmath.scale value, but related to the dynamic whole application ini_set using? The reason was there: I tried to be more absract.

Answer (score 5):

You have to put it on the following path:

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider
```

on boot function

Comment: Thank you SO much for this (two years ago). I've spent a lot of time trying to figure out why my settings weren't working elsewhere and this saved the day. Any idea why it has to be done here? Even my xdebug.ini file settings weren't working...